# Is need to have HTTPS for youtube Data API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have tried to insert commments to youtube still i have got :

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."
 }
}
```

Please Help me to Solve this Issue :-)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You opened this same question yesterday.  I gave you an answer on that question. Please dont open a new question continue on your original question.

Answer (score 1):

The error code 403 is saying **Access is forbidden**. It can also be because its not properly *authorized*.

You can try OAuth 2.0 authorization. Theres a bunch of other people that asked the same thing so if you search it you might find more info.